# Running Spring Integration within Windows Service; Does Not "Trigger" Inbound

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, windows-services, spring-integration

I've got a Spring Boot command line application using Spring Integration. The application is running within a service wrapper.

At start up, everything seems to run smoothly with no exceptions. However, if I drop a file in the observed directory nothing triggers the inbound-channel-adapter.

Is it at all possible the service wrapper is causing the polling to not run?

**UPDATE**
I added a logback.xml configuration

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.integration" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

But now the log is not receiving any input with this config. STDOUT works fine without the config. Makes is difficult to enable DEBUG for the integration package.

I based my wrapper on [this project](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/spring-boot-daemon)

**UPDATE #2**

I finally got logging working. I had a mistake in assuming it was not a ERROR level issue.

```
13:29:52.925 [task-scheduler-10] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: The path [\\server\sharepath] does not denote a properly accessible directory.
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:293)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` to observe polling activity.

Comment: Also, I'm working on a smaller example of my project since it would not be wise to share the source here.

Comment: You really should share the code. However first of all be sure that your application works well without service wrapper, as regular `java -jar` command. Check if your ` inbound-channel-adapter` isn't marked with `auto-startup="false"`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan definitely works without the service wrapper. In fact, at the moment the application running in the foreground (eww)

Comment: If you have STDOUT, share them here please! We would like to know how it is there with Spring Integration components.

Comment: Found out it was an error that for some reason didn't surface previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the network path cannot be determined if accessible by Java/Spring.

> 13:29:52.925 [task-scheduler-10] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler -
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: The path
>   [\server\sharepath] does not denote a properly accessible directory.